# App widget on click working on emulator but on real device works for the first time then onclick is never responded

Tags: android, android-studio, android-widget, android-appwidget, appwidgetprovider

I had been searching a lot for 2 days but nothing is working. I am beginner and trying my hands on app widget. I am trying to make a digital clock widget that opens clock on click. But unfortunately click not works on real device. It works in emulator fine but not work on real device.
My appwidgetProvider

```
package com.example.secondtrywidget;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetManager;
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetProvider;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;

import android.provider.AlarmClock;
import android.widget.RemoteViews;
 public class ExampleAppWidgetProvider extends AppWidgetProvider {
    @Override
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
    for (int appWidgetId : appWidgetIds) {


        RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.example_widget);
        //Intent openClockIntent=new Intent(context,ExampleAppWidgetProvider.class);
        //openClockIntent.setAction(AlarmClock.ACTION_SHOW_ALARMS);
        Intent openClockIntent = new Intent(AlarmClock.ACTION_SHOW_ALARMS);
        openClockIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, openClockIntent, 0);
        views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.example_widget_button, pendingIntent);
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);

    }
}

}
```

My Configuration

```
package com.example.secondtrywidget;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetManager;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.AlarmClock;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.RemoteViews;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText;
import com.skydoves.colorpickerpreference.ColorEnvelope;
import com.skydoves.colorpickerpreference.ColorListener;
import com.skydoves.colorpickerpreference.ColorPickerView;

    public class ExampleAppWidgetConfig extends AppCompatActivity {
    CheckBox checkbox;
    TextInputEditText hexcode;
    RadioGroup zonegroup;
    TextView demo;
    ColorPickerView colorPickerView;
    int init=R.color.clockcolor;

    private int appWidgetId = AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_example_app_widget_config);
    zonegroup=findViewById(R.id.zonegroup);
    zonegroup.clearCheck();
    demo=findViewById(R.id.demo);
    zonegroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup radioGroup, int i) {
            RadioButton rdb=(RadioButton)radioGroup.findViewById(i);
        }
    });
    colorPickerView=findViewById(R.id.colorPickerView);

    colorPickerView.setColorListener(new ColorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onColorSelected(ColorEnvelope colorEnvelope) {
            init=colorEnvelope.getColor();
            demo.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#"+Integer.toHexString(init)));
        }
    });

    checkbox=findViewById(R.id.checkbox);
    hexcode=findViewById(R.id.hexcode);
    findViewById(R.id.color1).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            init=R.color.color1;
            demo.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.color1));

        }
    });
    findViewById(R.id.color2).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            init=R.color.color2;
            demo.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.color2));
        }
    });
    findViewById(R.id.color3).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            init=R.color.color3;
            demo.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.color3));
        }
    });
    findViewById(R.id.color4).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            init=R.color.color4;
            demo.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.color4));
        }
    });
    findViewById(R.id.color5).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            init=R.color.color5;
            demo.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.color5));
        }
    });
    findViewById(R.id.color6).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            init=R.color.color6;
            demo.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.color6));
        }
    });
    findViewById(R.id.color7).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            init=R.color.color7;
            demo.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.color7));
        }
    });
    findViewById(R.id.color8).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            init=R.color.color8;
            demo.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.color8));
        }
    });
    findViewById(R.id.color9).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            init=R.color.color9;
            demo.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.color9));
        }
    });

    Intent configIntent = getIntent();
    Bundle extras = configIntent.getExtras();
    if (extras != null) {
        appWidgetId = extras.getInt(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID,
                AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID);
    }
    Intent resultValue = new Intent();
    resultValue.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, appWidgetId);
    setResult(RESULT_CANCELED, resultValue);
    if (appWidgetId == AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID) {
        finish();
    }
   // editTextButton = findViewById(R.id.edit_text_button);
    }
    public void confirmConfiguration(View v) {

    if(init<0)
    {
        init=R.color.clockcolor;
    }
    String color="#"+Integer.toHexString(getResources().getColor(init));
    if(checkbox.isChecked()&&!(hexcode.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("")))
    {
        color=hexcode.getText().toString();
    }

    String hrtw=null;
    String hrtf=null;
    int selectedId=zonegroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
    if(selectedId==-1||selectedId==R.id.smallhour)hrtw="hh:mm";
    else if(selectedId==R.id.largehour)hrtf="k:mm";


    AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(this);
   // String buttonText = editTextButton.getText().toString();
    RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(this.getPackageName(), R.layout.example_widget);

    views.setTextColor(R.id.simpleDigitaldate, Color.parseColor(color));
    views.setTextColor(R.id.simpleDigitalClock, Color.parseColor(color));
    views.setCharSequence(R.id.simpleDigitalClock,"setFormat12Hour",hrtw);
    views.setCharSequence(R.id.simpleDigitalClock,"setFormat24Hour",hrtf);

    //Intent openClockIntent=new Intent(ExampleAppWidgetConfig.this,ExampleAppWidgetProvider.class);
    //openClockIntent.setAction(AlarmClock.ACTION_SHOW_ALARMS);
    Intent openClockIntent = new Intent(AlarmClock.ACTION_SHOW_ALARMS);
    openClockIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, openClockIntent, 
    PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.example_widget_button,pendingIntent);

    appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);
    Intent resultValue = new Intent();
    resultValue.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, appWidgetId);
    setResult(RESULT_OK, resultValue);
    finish();
}

}
```

My Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.secondtrywidget">
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.alarm.permission.SET_ALARM"/>
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/logo"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@drawable/logo"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <receiver android:name=".ExampleAppWidgetProvider">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
            <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_ENABLED" />
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
            android:resource="@xml/exampe_appwidget_info" />
    </receiver>
    <activity android:name=".ExampleAppWidgetConfig"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_CONFIGURE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

My info

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appwidget-provider xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:configure="com.example.secondtrywidget.ExampleAppWidgetConfig"
android:initialLayout="@layout/example_widget"
android:minHeight="40dp"
android:minResizeWidth="40dp"
android:minWidth="110dp"
android:resizeMode="vertical|horizontal"
android:updatePeriodMillis="3600000"
android:widgetCategory="home_screen">

</appwidget-provider>
```

Please Help somebody to resolve the problem as i am eager to make widget but this problem halted my learning.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything you explicitly did "wrong" but I was suspecting its to do with deceleration context since RemoteViews can act funny in that regard.

Moving your intents variable deceleration outside the for loop will fix your bug.
Its better coding practice anyway.

```
Intent openClockIntent = new Intent(AlarmClock.ACTION_SHOW_ALARMS);
openClockIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, openClockIntent, 0);

for (int appWidgetId : appWidgetIds) {
    RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.example_widget);
    views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.example_widget_button, pendingIntent);
    appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);
}
```

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But i tried that way but still it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

What is your real device? Some Samsung phones (for example my Galaxy S21) require SET_ALARM permission to get to AlarmClock.ACTION_SHOW_ALARMS. Try requesting that permission in your AndroidManifest.xml, which worked for me.

In general it's always worth testing the `Intent` that you're going to embed in the `PendingIntent` inside your own app first, where you can catch exceptions if it doesn't work.

Incidentally I have a working Digital Clock widget which does start the built-in clock app on my Samsung Galaxy S21. I was going to wait until I had improved the configurator a bit more before posting the code on github, but I'll post it now (it will take an hour or two to prepare a github version and put it there) to help you and anyone else who has problems getting this type of widget to work properly.

Comment: Now posted on github at  rparkins999 /
AndroidSecondsClockWidget